# When I try to call out specific data in a for loop The error says: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python

I'm using nested lists and while printing certain values in a list it is giving me an error,

> `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

I'm new to Python and I've been using nested loops. I don't know what this error means and I don't have friends that code. I've tried troubleshooting but I still can't figure it out.

This is the portion of my code where I am getting an issue

```
chaal = [1, 4.55]
chicken = [2, 19.80]
onionpaste = [1, 2.50]
garlicpaste = [1, 2.50]
onion = [1, 2.95]
garlic = [1, 2.95]
ginger = [1, 4.60]
masala = [1, 5.70]
ghee = [1, 4.40]
ingredients = [
    ["chaal", chaal],
    ["whole chicken", chicken],
    ["onion paste", onionpaste],
    ["garlic paste", garlicpaste],
    ["onion", onion],
    ["garlic", garlic],
    ["ginger", ginger],
    ["garam masala", masala],
    ['Ghee', ghee]
]

print("These are the ingredients you will need for the dish:")

for i in range(len(ingredients)):
    print(ingredients[i, 0])
```

I expect the output to print out the name of each ingredient in the list.

Comment: It is a very literal error, `ingredient[i, 0]` is accessing the list with a tuple. Try `ingredients[i][0]`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have true multi-dimensional arrays, so you can't write a two-index expression like `[i, 0]`. Instead you are dealing with a list of lists; dereference the main list, e.g. `ingredients[i]`, to get a list; then you can index into *this* list with a second index, i.e. `ingredients[i][0]`. This does in one step the equivalent of

```
temp = ingredients[i]
print(temp[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```py
for i in range(len(ingredients)):  # iterate by index
    print(ingredients[i][0])
```

or:

```py
for i in ingredients:  # iterate by element
    print(i[0])
```

Output of solution 1:

```
chaal
whole chicken
onion paste
garlic paste
onion
garlic
ginger
garam masala
Ghee
```

Solution 2:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array(ingredients)
print(a[:,:1])  # slicing by numpy array
```

Output of solution 2:

```
[['chaal']
 ['whole chicken']
 ['onion paste']
 ['garlic paste']
 ['onion']
 ['garlic']
 ['ginger']
 ['garam masala']
 ['Ghee']]
```